# Aerospike 3.6.4 list insert operation giving 'Server error'

Tags: go, aerospike

I am using the aerospike list operation (golang client) to prepend to an existing key in aerospike using the following command:

> client.Operate(c.WritePolicy, aeroKey, aero.ListInsertOp(c.bin, 0,
>   messages...))

But I am getting "Server error" as response error and no other error details. I already checked that the aeroKey exists and is not nil. Could it be that the aerospike version does not support this operation? Is there a way to confirm this problem or some setting to allow this operation ?

Comment: For starters, post your client and server versions.

Comment: is there a way I can do it from the client itself ? Because I do not have access to the actual aerospike server

Comment: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/whats-a-quick-way-to-get-aerospike-server-version-details-build-number-etc/1525

Comment: ya..but how can i run this "asinfo -v build" from the golang client (via the code)?

Comment: ok I got this one . c.client.GetNodes()[0].RequestInfo("")

Comment: so..my aerospike version is "Aerospike Community Edition build 3.6.4"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that would be because the list API was added in [release 3.7.0.1](https://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#3.7.0.1). Before that lists were a data type without any atomic operations (list-append, etc). Same thing goes for maps, before 3.8.4 they were just a container for map data.

You're running against a [version](https://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#3.6.4) that is two years old. Time to upgrade.